# Angular and overlay - switch ON | OFF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, overlay

I'm actually on a 1.2.16 Angular Project.

I want to create an overlay, which turns on and off with a button.
Naturally, this button should not be in the overlay since it must remain available to disable the overlay.

What is the best way to achieve this? A feature of Angular, or just using a standard CSS / JS?

Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 1):

Just look at this example:

```
<body>
  <div id="overlay" ng-if="vm.showOverlay"></div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="vm.showOverlay = true">Open Overlay</button>
</body>
```

Then you can style your overlay using standard CSS, e.g. `position: fixed;` etc.

Also, look at [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) module, it will provide you with ready-made overlay windows.